AWS Bedrock Claude Sonnet 3.5 with image and system prompt
I need to invoke a Bedrock Claude Sonnet 3.5 model with:

System prompt
An Image that I have in .JPEG locally in the disk
a context in text
a query

Im getting an error in JSON payload with the image.
A client error occured: messages.0.content.1.image.source: Field required

My code:
def generate_conversation_bedrock(bedrock_client, model_id, input_text, input_image, max_tokens):

    response = client.invoke_model(
        modelId=model_id,
        body=json.dumps(
            {
                "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
                "max_tokens": max_tokens,
                "system": sys_msg,
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "role": "user",
                        "content": [
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": input_text
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "image",
                                "image": {
                                    "format": "jpeg",
                                    "source": {
                                        "media_type": "image/jpeg",
                                        "data": input_image_base64  # Contiene la imagen en formato base64
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
            }
        ),
    )
    response_body = json.loads(response.get("body").read())
    return response_body

def main():
    model_id = "anthropic.claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620-v1:0"
    input_text = "describe la  imagen"
    input_image = "./combined_image.jpg"
    image = resize_and_compress_image(input_image)
    input_image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image).decode('utf-8')
   
    try:
        bedrock_client = boto3.client(service_name="bedrock-runtime", region_name="us-east-1")
        response = generate_conversation_bedrock(bedrock_client, model_id, input_text, input_image_base64, 1024)
        
        for output in response.get("content", []):
            print(output["text"])
     

    
    except ClientError as err:
        message = err.response['Error']['Message']
        print(f"A client error occured: {message}")

   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In resize_and_compress_image I turn the size of the image into the model input limits.

did you try to use the full image path ?

I had the same error and how it worked to me:
with open('imagePath', "rb") as f:
        image = f.read()
        image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image).decode('utf-8') 

    bedrock_runtime = boto3.client('bedrock-runtime', region_name='us-east-1')

    kwargs = {
        "modelId": "anthropic.claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620-v1:0",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "body": json.dumps({
            "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
            "max_tokens": 10000,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "image",
                            "source": {
                                "type": "base64",
                                "media_type": "image/jpeg",
                                "data": image_base64
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "What's in these images?"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
    }

    response = bedrock_runtime.invoke_model(**kwargs)

    body = json.loads(response['body'].read())

